# Can we append the output result to the same HDFS location of different MR Job's?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, batch-processing

can we append the output results of different MR Jobs to a particular HDFS which already has some data of some previous MR job. The reason why am asking is am running a batch process where i want to get the output of all the MR jobs in a single output file which follows CSV format so that i can load the Hive table in one shot.

Comment: Did you tried using -getmerge command?

Comment: But that would merge the data after all the jobs are finished writing to different output directory, as i am running for some one month of data which is partitioned based on hours i should be creating separate output paths each time and finally making them merge so reducing this process was my objective of the question.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the map reduce job? You can specify the output directory in case you are using hadoop streaming and pig. As for hive, create an external table pointing at the directory - it does not matter whether there is one large file or a collection of smaller files.

Comment: Yeah would do that finally, but now for the testing purpose am running the my jar on Hadoop cluster through a cron job where the script consists of same jar and output directory but am only changing the input path so after each job finishes its overwriting the output path but i want it to be appended in the output path file i have mentioned.